# Fragment layout not displaying anything?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

IN this layout i have made tab layout with fragment activity and wanted to display few things,however nothing is being shown in fragment activity.
This is the base xml where the fragment is being made change.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_change"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
    tools:context="com.example.alpit.formula2.Change">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/change_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/change"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/change_tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabGravity="fill">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/change_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/change_appbar"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationTheme">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the java code of the tab layout

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Distance extends Fragment {


    protected View onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_distance, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is the xml code of distance

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_distance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.alpit.formula2.Distance"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Weight in kg" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Weight in kg" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Weight in kg"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Weight in kg" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my java code of adding tabs in the layout

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class Change extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle3;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.change);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_change);
        toggle3 = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.Close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle3);
        toggle3.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_change);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        setTitle("Conversion");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.change_viewpager);
        setUpViewpager(viewPager);
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.change_tab);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (toggle3.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)) {
            return true;
        }
        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }

    private void setUpViewpager(ViewPager upViewpager) {
        Adapter_tab adapter = new Adapter_tab(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Distance(), "Distance");
        adapter.addFragment(new Mass(), "Mass");
        upViewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    static class Adapter_tab extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter_tab(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentTitleList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What does `made tab layout with fragment activity` mean? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It means i am having a 2 tabs in an activity,which are fragments .

Comment: I can't see the 2 Tabs. Answer my previous question.

Comment: Wait m giving my java code of it,i have done it via java

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Any help.. ????

Answer (score 1):

just add onCreateView in Distance